Find duplicate phone from json column with whereIn in Laravel
How can I find duplicate phones from json column with whereIn in Laravel. Below is my code?
    // Orders table migration
    $table->json("recipient")->nullable();

    // Data castings in Order Model
    protected $casts = [
        "recipient" => "array"
    ];

    // Order created
    $order = Order::create([
        "recipient" => [
            "phone" => "1234424532",
            "email" => "name@example.com"
        ],
        "status"  => "completed"
    ]);

    // Try to retrieve the recipients with duplicate phone numbers
    $query = Order::query();
    return $query->select('id', 'recipient')
        ->whereNotNull('recipient')
        ->whereIn('recipient->phone', function ($subQuery) {
            $subQuery->select('recipient->phone AS phone')
                ->from('orders')
                ->groupBy('phone')
                ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
        })->paginate();

It did not work. Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Enter the code below to see a list of duplicate phone results. I am hoping it is working for you.
$query = Order::query();
    //get all duplicate phone from json
    $duplicates = DB::table('orders')
        ->select(DB::raw('recipient->>"$.phone" as phone'))
        ->groupBy('phone')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
    
    //match all record with duplicate record
    return $query->select('id', 'recipient')
        ->joinSub($duplicates, 'duplicate_phones', function ($join) {
            $join->on(DB::raw('recipient->>"$.phone"'), '=', 'duplicate_phones.phone');
        })
        ->paginate();


if above solution is not helpful then please create dummy data and what result you expected that is edit your question then i will give you correct result

In the question duplicate result finding in 1 main query. i joined 1 another for particular duplicate records of main query.

Comment added inside code

Sorry for the late response. I am starting to test your solution right now.

I just tested and it worked. Thanks :)

@ Zealous System Hello, it worked locally but not in the production environment. I got a syntax error: production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>>"$.phone" = duplicate_phones.phone where status in (?, ?, ?) and cre...' at line 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from orders inner join (select json_unquote(json_extract(recipient, '$."phone"')) as phonefromorderswherestatus` in...

Issue is fixed by replacing from DB::raw('recipient->>"$.phone"') to DB::raw('json_unquote(json_extract(recipient, "$.phone"))')
